# Beautifying HTML with JSP mixed in

Tags: html, jsp, coding-style

Does anyone know of an HTML beautifier that can deal with (or at least ignore) JSP? I've searched high and low... I'm not looking for an HTML validator, just something that can format the file decently (i.e. indentation).

Comment: Would it not be preferable to write neat code from the start ;)

Comment: Netbeans can (re)format JSP's

Comment: Neat code would be ideal for sure, but it's not mine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most good IDE's will let you say which code template to use as default within another file extension.

So i use PHPstorm in which i can say, for example that a *.jsp will use `html` first and then `jsp`. This way the page will display and reformat my code with the correct spacings and what not.

Worth looking into which IDE you are using, assuming you're using one :)

Comment: i hear a lot of chatter about this. I hear its super extendable? Just from users writing addons for it.

Comment: Yeah there are loads of addons for it.

Comment: @JamieHutber: Can you perhaps explain how/where you set this in PHPStorm?